# Static members and LNK error in C++

Tags: c++, static

I have a class that has a static member, which I want to use in the class constructor, but the code doesn't compile, and I'm left with these errors:

> fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
>
> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class Collection A::collection"

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

*a.h:*

```
class A
{
protected:
 static Collection<A*> collection;
};
```

*a.cpp:*

```
A::A() {
 A::collection.push_back(this);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my C++ program link when my class has static members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976983/why-wont-my-c-program-link-when-my-class-has-static-members)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add

```
Collection<A*> A::collection;
```

to your a.cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

In your .cpp you need to add:

```
Collection<A*> A::collection;
```

The .h only declared that there would be a copy somewhere. You need to provide that copy in the .cpp.

Answer (score 1):

alternatively, if you don't want to put that line in a cpp file, you can use a static method which returns a reference to a static instance... i.e.

```
class A
{
public:
  static Collection<A*>& collection()
  {
    static Collection<A*> singleInstance;
    return singleInstance;
  }
};
```