# C++ static var. Does not compile

Tags: c++, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [static members and LNK error in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043495/static-members-and-lnk-error-in-c)
>   [What does it mean to have an undefined reference to a static member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-undefined-reference-to-a-static-member)

I have this class:

```
class A_GItem  
{
public:        
void create_item();    
private:
  static int static_index;  
}
```

The create_item function is as simply as:

```
void create_item() { static_index++; }
```

When compile (after a clean, trying to solve the problem  ) I have : 
 *error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static int A_GItem::static_index*

Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Member static variables require initialization. You are merely declaring your variable in your header, but not defining it:

```
//A_GItem.h
class A_GItem  
{
public:        
void create_item();    
private:
  static int static_index;  
}

//A_GItem.cpp
int A_GItem::static_index = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually define the static member varible

```
int A_GItem::static_index;
```

in one of .cpp files.