# Static QList of QObject pointers to keep track of siblings?

Tags: c++, qt, list, pointers, static-members

I would like to keep track of `thisClass` (inherits QObject) instances ("siblings") by appending `this` (the pointer to self) to a "shared" static [QList](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#details) class member:

```
private:
  static QList<thisClass*> _plist;
```

However, the `static` member declaration causes an LNK2001 unresolved external symbol. Without `static`, the program builds (but each object only has its own data).

What might cause the error, is there a fix, and how should "keeping track of class instances" be done properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my C++ program link when my class has static members?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976983/why-wont-my-c-program-link-when-my-class-has-static-members)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared static member. Now you need to define it in cpp file:

`QList<thisClass*> thisClass::_plist;`

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is only a *declaration*, you also need to *define* the member variable. This is done in one of your source files.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need random access iteration of the list, you could also use an intrusive container to allow iteration of the siblings: it'd have lower overhead, as the list nodes are stored in the objects themselves. The list can be iterated just like `std::list`, and it tracks the dynamic lifetime of the objects - it's not unlike like a `QPointer`, except that it's a list.

```
// myclass.h - interface
#include <QObject>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
class MyClass : public QObject, private boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
  using list_t = boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>;
  static list_t m_siblings;
  friend list_t;
  static QThread const *listThread() {
    return m_siblings.empty() ? QThread::currentThread() : m_siblings.front().thread();
  }
protected:
  bool event(QEvent * ev) override {
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::ThreadChange)
      Q_ASSERT(m_siblings.size() <= 1);
    return QObject::event(ev);
  }
public:
  MyClass(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject{parent} {
    Q_ASSERT(listThread() == QThread::current_thread());
    m_siblings.push_back(*this);
    qDebug() << "there are" << m_siblings.size() << "objects in existence";
  }
  ~MyClass() override {
    m_list.erase(m_siblings.iterator_to(*this));
  }
};

// myclass.cpp - implementation
#include "myclass.h"
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass> MyClass::m_siblings;
```

It is enforced that all siblings are in the same thread; this is necessary for thread-safe access of the list. If the objects were to live in arbitrary threads, the list access needs to be protected by a mutex:

```
// myclass.h - interface
#include <QObject>
#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>
class MyClass : public QObject, private boost::intrusive::list_base_hook<> {
  using list_t = boost::intrusive::list<MyClass>;
  static QReadWriteLock m_siblingsMutex;
  static list_t m_siblings;
  friend list_t;
public:
  MyClass(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject{parent} {
    QWriteLocker lock(&m_siblingsMutex);
    m_siblings.push_back(*this);
  }
  ~MyClass() override {
    QWriteLocker lock(&m_siblingsMutex);
    m_siblings.erase(m_siblings.iterator_to(*this));
  }
  void dumpSiblings() {
    QReadLocker lock(&m_siblingsMutex);
    for (auto const &obj : m_siblings)
       qDebug() << "MyClass at " << &obj;
};

// myclass.cpp - implementation
#include "myclass.h"
QReadWriteLock MyClass::m_siblingsMutex;
boost::intrusive::list<MyClass> MyClass::m_siblings;
```